# Error With Composer Update

Tags: symfony, laravel, composer-php

Someone know how fix the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom' not found
```

my `composer.json` is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "way/generators": "1.0.*@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Authority": "app/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "php artisan optimize"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

any idea? I think is due the laravel version o due the cloned repository version.

Comment: What about updating Laravel to 4.2?

Comment: The error with composer install is:Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/filesystem 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out how fix it.

I used the follow composer.json

{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "~2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "way/generators": "~2.6",
        "mockery/mockery": "~0.9",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Authority": "app/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "php artisan optimize"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}

and now everything is working.

Thanks Everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to redownload your packages:

```
cd /your/application/dir

rm bootstrap/compiled.php

rm -rf vendor

rm composer.lock

composer install
```

Then you can

```
composer update --dev
```

Again

Comment: Hello When I Did it. the following error appear Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not found

Answer (score 0):

update this:

{ "require": { "laravel/framework": "4.0.*", 
"cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*", 
"mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev", 
"phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*" },

try this later

rm -rf vendor 
  rm composer.lock 
  composer install 
  composer update

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider' not found

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of `vendor/symfony/security-core/Symfony/Component/Security/Core`

`$ ll vendor/symfony/security-core/Symfony/Component/Security/Core
total 0`

I found out I had no files. So i did delete it and updated again:

```
$ rm vendor/symfony/security-core/ -rf                          

$ phpcomposer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to open https://packagist.org/packages.json (Could not resolve host: packagist.org)
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.3)
    Loading from cache

symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/validator (For using the user password constraint)
symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using the expression voter)
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

Now it works.